# Understanding J array

Tags: arrays, j

Starting with something simple:

```
a =: 3 4 $ i.12
```

This creates a nice 3 x 4 matrix.

So when I try

```
b=: a $ i.5
```

I get a very long output for b. I do not understand what the output is (by the way, i.5 was arbitrary). By which I mean, I don't nderstand what $ means when it has a 2+ dimensional array as a left hand argument.
Can someone explain what b is describing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what happens:
a becomes matrix

```
0 1  2  3
4 5  6  7
8 9 10 11
```

as  you just described.
$ has dyadic rank of 1 _, which means it applies rows of left argument to the entire right argument and pastes result together.
`a $ i.5` is `(0 1 2 3 $ i.5),(4 5 6 7 $ i.5),:(8 9 10 11 $ i.5)`

All the subarrays have different shape, so they are coerced into least common shape that would fit them all, which in this case is `8 9 10 11`. Therefore, the result has shape `3 8 9 10 11`